# Issue with a mysql query going from MySQL to MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm currently porting a website from PHP 5 using old mysql functions, so I basically started by replacing all of the mysql functions with the new mysqli ones and instantly got rid of most of the issues. The thing is, there is a mysql query that doesn't work anymore and I don't understand why, here is what it looks like:

```sql
    SELECT *
    FROM { 
      OJ `tableA`.`tableA`
      LEFT OUTER JOIN `tableB`.`tableB` ON `tableA`.`idA` = `tableB`.`idA`
    }
    LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableC.idC = tableB.idC
    LEFT JOIN tableD ON tableD.idD = tableC.idC
    WHERE something in ('tableA','tableB')
    ORDER BY column1, column2
```

**Error says:**

> "Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableC .idC = tableB.idC' at line 6"

I want to say that I did not make the website nor I know who made it, I'm just in charge of porting it to the newer version of PHP. So I can't say for sure what this query is about, but I didn't think I would encounter such problem.
Also, I'm not familiar with this `OJ {}` writing so I'm not sure how I could replace it in case it was the issue here.

Comment: FWIW, OJ {} is exactly where my eyes land. That’s weird.

Comment: It's a non-standard way of writing OUTER JOINS, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html or [Understanding the use of curly braces and "OJ" in a SQL query](//stackoverflow.com/q/6767060)

Comment: Yeah, it's weird, I've never seen that before, I assume it means Outer Join but how is it an outer join on nothing ? I don't understand how it's written

Comment: ok but is it the problem here ?

Comment: I would check mariaDb to see if that’s supported. I work with DB2 and I think it would barf because there should be a name for the table defined by the brackets. But I don’t know for sure since I’ve never seen this syntax before.

Comment: Ok I fixed it by removing the curly braces and OJ and writting simply FROM tableA .... Should I edit my post to put the answer ?

Comment: Btw, the error message comes from mysql (mariadb?), not from php, so the php upgrade (and tag) is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OPs fix for MariaDB was:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB.tableB ON tableA.idA = tableB.idA
LEFT JOIN tableC ON tableC.idC = tableB.idC
LEFT JOIN tableD ON tableD.idD = tableC.idC
WHERE something in ('tableA','tableB')
ORDER BY column1, column2
```

> Ok I fixed it by removing the curly braces and OJ and writting simply FROM tableA ....  – Simon 13 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

The [MariaDB parser](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/10.4/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L11953) seems to only have a single `table_ref` in the braces.

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) and also [parser](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/8.0/sql/sql_yacc.yy#L10649) has a boarder definition.

If you which for MariaDB to support the wider format you can create a [bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org/)

Comment: Ok thank you, I don't really need to write it like that, so I just figured out how to write it otherwise.

Comment: I was interested so I looked - interesting question and like previous comments my initial reaction was WTF/huh '{ OF ' !!!?